# How do I handle divide by zero using try except in Python (I am a newbie coder)

Tags: python

How do I handle divide by zero using try except in Python

```
op_dictNns = dict(result2.compute().values)
dictNns = {k: NNS1(op_dictNns[k], v, float(1-(op_dictNns[k]/v)), float((1-(op_dictNns[k]/v)) * 0.15)) for k, v in dict(dataNns.values).items()}

op_dict = dict(result.compute().values)
dict2 = {k: Summary(op_dict[k], v, float(op_dict[k] / v), float(op_dict[k] / v) * 0.70) for k, v in dict(data.values).items()}

op_dict3 = dict(result1.compute().values)
dict3 = {k: Mandate(op_dict3[k], v, float(op_dict3[k]/op_dict[k]), float(op_dict3[k]/op_dict[k]) * 0.15) for k, v in dict(data.values).items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `ZeroDivisionError` Exception :

```
try:
    print(12/0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Can't divide by zero !")
```

```
#ouput :
#Can't divide by zero !
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
try:
    op_dict = dict(result.compute().values)
    dict2 = {k: Summary(op_dict[k], v, float(op_dict[k] / v), float(op_dict[k] / v) * 0.70) for k, v in dict(data.values).items()}

    op_dict3 = dict(result1.compute().values)
    dict3 = {k: Mandate(op_dict3[k], v, float(op_dict3[k]/op_dict[k]), float(op_dict3[k]/op_dict[k]) * 0.15) for k, v in dict(data.values).items()}
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('ZeroDivisionError')
```

Comment: Please consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help future readers to better understand your solution.